# Solve for x in this equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

\begin{align*}
\sqrt{x+6} -\sqrt{x+1} = 1
\end{align*}

the obvious solution is $x=3$ but I don't know how to factorize how should I approach this problem.

Comment: Is the equation correct? If $x=3$, its LHS is equal to $-1$, not $1$.

Comment: A standard method is to move one square root to the right-hand side: $\sqrt{x+6} = 1 + \sqrt{x+1} $, then square ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\sqrt{x+6}+\sqrt{x+1}=b$, so we have
\begin{align*}
    b\cdot 1=\left(\sqrt{x+6}+\sqrt{x+1}\right)\cdot \left(\sqrt{x+6}-\sqrt{x+1}\right)=(x+6)-(x+1)=5
\end{align*}
which implies $b=5$, then
\begin{align*}
    2\sqrt{x+6}=\left(\sqrt{x+6}+\sqrt{x+1}\right)+\left(\sqrt{x+6}-\sqrt{x+1}\right)=5+1=6
\end{align*}
we get
\begin{align*}
    \sqrt{x+6}=3\Rightarrow x+6=9\Rightarrow x=3
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

alternatively , let $(x+1)=u^2$
so we have $x+6=u^2+5$

so $\sqrt{u^2+5}=1-u$

which can be solved easily to get u=-2

thus x=3